# Updating results of a question asked to open ai when rerun

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain

I'm working on a project to ask OpenAi to generate a Python program based on the question asked using prompt engineering.

I ask it to return its thoughts and the program code in a .csv file separately and then extract the program code in a `solution.py` file and then run some unit tests. All of this is done in a single execution of my code. There can only be one solution.py file, but multiple csv are allowed.

My question is, assuming my unit tests fail and I choose to rerun the above program 5 times, is there a way to use my previous .csv to improve my solution.py?

I'm using langchain and python if it helps

TLDR: is there a way to identify if this is my first run of the program or a follow up? and is there a way to leverage the previous solution to generate a better one ?